# there is issue in case expression

Tags: sql, case

```
SELECT ENAME,SAL,
    CASE SAL
        WHEN 'SAL<1000' THEN 'LOWER'
        WHEN 'SAL>1000' THEN 'HIGH'
    END
    RESULT FROM EMP;
```

This gives an error:

> inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s

What should I do to fix my query?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT ENAME,SAL,
    CASE WHEN SAL<1000 THEN 'LOWER'
         WHEN SAL>1000 THEN 'HIGH'
    END AS RESULT
FROM EMP;
```

Comment: this one not working..error output:- invalid relational operator

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend:

```
SELECT ENAME, SAL,
       (CASE WHEN SAL < 1000 THEN 'LOWER'
             WHEN SAL > 1000 THEN 'HIGH'
        END) as RESULT
FROM EMP;
```

There are two issues:

- You have single quotes around the comparisons.  A string is not appropriate in this context.
- You have `SAL` right after `CASE`, which is also not appropriate.